# make says: `No rule to make target` when I try to compile a Qt application for android platfrom

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, android-ndk, qt-creator

I wanted to compile [this project](https://github.com/redkite1/qtelnetperso) for android platform. I simply downloaded it and selected all android kits after I opened the `TelnetWidgetTest.pro` file in `Qt creator`. Now the project could be compiled successfully if I choose (Android for x86 GCC4.9 Qt 5.5.0) but I got the following error when I select (Android for armeabi-v7a GCC 4.9 Qt 5.5.0):

```
mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target '..\..\..\..\AppData\Roaming\IDM\android-ndk-r10d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\include\profile\impl\profiler_hashtable_size.h', needed by 'build\mainwindowimpl.obj'.  Stop.
17:43:33: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\Tools\mingw492_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project TelnetWidgetTest (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.5.0))
When executing step "Make"
```

If I choose (kit: Android for armeabi (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.5.0)) It also returns the following error:

```
    mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target '..\..\..\..\AppData\Roaming\IDM\android-ndk-r10d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\include\profile\impl\profiler_map_to_unordered_map.h', needed by 'build\mainwindowimpl.obj'.  Stop.
17:42:38: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\Tools\mingw492_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project TelnetWidgetTest (kit: Android for armeabi (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.5.0))
When executing step "Make"
```

The program could be compiled and run successfully in windows desktop.

1. What does it mean when make tells `**No rule to make target**` ? I checked the mentioned folders the files exist and path to android `NDK` is correct. So what the real problem is?
2. Another question is that, What is `profiler_map_to_unordered_map.h` and why it is needed by one of my object files (`mainwindowimpl.obj`).

Answer (score 2):

Just yesterday I bumped into a similar issue. After a rather painful investigation I found that the culprit is path length!

If I create a project:

```
`c:\x\12345678901234567890123456789012345.pro`
```

which creates build directory

```
`c:\build-12345678901234567890123456789012345-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_9_0_for_Android_armv7-Debug`
```

(109 characters) with Android SDK in

```
`c:\Users\miroslav.kropacek\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`
```

it creates paths in `Makefile` like:

```
`..\Users\miroslav.kropacek\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\include\profile\impl\profiler_map_to_unordered_map.h`
```

(150 characters)

One (less comfortable) solution is to rename your project file, in my example shortening it by one character from `12345678901234567890123456789012345` to `1234567890123456789012345678901234` is enough to make it compile.

Another solution is to manually take care in Qt creator's dialog for build directories specification, and enter something less offending there (like simple "release" and "debug" directories) but you have to remember to do that every time you pull sources from scratch.

And yet another solution is copying Android SDK to `C:\Android\sdk` which leads to following path in `Makefile`:

```
`..\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\include\profile\impl\profiler_map_to_unordered_map.h`
```

(112 characters) and works OK.

Without looking into source code I can only speculate that the culprit is mingw's `make` which creates a buffer [260 characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath) long so when the relative path is resolving, it gets as long as:

```
`c:\build-12345678901234567890123456789012345-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_9_0_for_Android_armv7-Debug\..\Users\miroslav.kropacek\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\include\profile\impl\profiler_map_to_unordered_map.h`
```

what happens to be exactly 260 characters and with `\0` it's exactly one character beyond with infamous Windows limit.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar error message.

Try cleaning up the built files and then recompile it all:

- Build > Clean All
- Build > Run qmake
- Build > Build All
- Build > Run

On each step, wait for it to complete before moving on the the next one.