# Erro trying to build qml lib to Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml

I'm using a qml lib with a qt c++ projetc, and work well in linux and windows, but when I try to build to Android I receive this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
09:40:07: The process "/home/ysaakue/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project IracemaCharts (kit: Android Qt 5.15.2 Clang Multi-Abi)
When executing step "Copy application data"
09:40:07: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

that is my build config:
[image]

and that is my android device config:
[image]

**EDIT:**
this is my .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = IracemaCharts
QT += qml quick
CONFIG += plugin c++11 qmltypes

QML_IMPORT_NAME = IracemaCharts
QML_IMPORT_MAJOR_VERSION = 0
QML_IMPORT_MINOR_VERSION = 1

TARGET = $$qtLibraryTarget($$TARGET)
uri = IracemaCharts

# Input
SOURCES += \
        iracemalineseries.cpp \
        iracemacharts_plugin.cpp \
        iracemacharts.cpp \
        iracemalineseriesview.cpp

HEADERS += \
        iracemalineseries.h \
        iracemacharts_plugin.h \
        iracemacharts.h \
        iracemalineseriesview.h

DISTFILES = qmldir

!equals(_PRO_FILE_PWD_, $$OUT_PWD) {
    copy_qmldir.target = $$OUT_PWD/qmldir
    copy_qmldir.depends = $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/qmldir
    copy_qmldir.commands = $(COPY_FILE) "$$replace(copy_qmldir.depends, /, $$QMAKE_DIR_SEP)" "$$replace(copy_qmldir.target, /, $$QMAKE_DIR_SEP)"
    QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += copy_qmldir
    PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$copy_qmldir.target
}

qmldir.files = qmldir
qmldir.files += plugins.qmltypes
unix {
    installPath = $$[QT_INSTALL_QML]/$$replace(uri, \., /)
    qmldir.path = $$installPath
    target.path = $$installPath
    copy_qmltypes.path = $$installPath
    copy_qmltypes.files = $$OUT_PWD/plugins.qmltypes
    INSTALLS += target qmldir copy_qmltypes
}

windows {
    installPath = $$[QT_INSTALL_QML]/$$replace(uri, \., /)
    installPath = $$replace(installPath, /, \\)
    qmldir.path = $$installPath
    target.path = $$installPath
    copy_qmltypes.path = $$installPath
    copy_qmltypes.files = $$OUT_PWD/plugins.qmltypes
    INSTALLS += target qmldir copy_qmltypes
}
```

I'm using Qt version 5.15.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was because this project is a lib, and in the default build steps has some to copy the files to target device, and in my case it isn't required, so I disabled(using the QtCreator interface as bellow) the last two stets and the problem was solved. (for now at least).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this lines to your project file(.pro):

```
# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Now it should work.

Comment: I got the same error with these warnings:
`warning: overriding recipe for target 'install_target'` , `warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'install_target'`, `warning: overriding recipe for target 'uninstall_target'`, `warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'uninstall_target`

Comment: I added my .pro file in the question

Comment: Hello again,
it's not as easy as i thought. I don't see the error, but hopefully you can find your solution in one of these links: [Android build: make: \*\*\* No rule to make target \`install\`. Stop.](https://forum.qt.io/topic/108935/android-build-make-no-rule-to-make-target-install-stop)  [make says: \`No rule to make target\` when I try to compile a Qt application for android platfrom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35381034/make-says-no-rule-to-make-target-when-i-try-to-compile-a-qt-application-for-a)